# Can a month be considered four weeks of work in employment case

Tags: employment, breach-of-contract

If I worked for a month I am entitled to 7 days pay in lieu of notice.
I worked from 10 Dec 2018 to 4 Jan 2019 four weeks. 
 Is there a case law example where four weeks is considered a month?

Comment: What jurisdiction? What entitles you to the 7-days pay; is it company policy or employment law in your location?

Comment: It depends in this case on the definition of what is a month. And whether it is considered I have worked a month.  I have worked 4 weeks.

Comment: It depends on the laws of your locality and may depend on the policies of the employer. Where was the job located (not the company name but the country and any other geographic identification) so that the laws can be examined. You are claiming that if you work a month you are entitled to 7 days pay. Is that claim based on your understanding of the local employment law or your company's policy? That is an important distinction. For example, if it is based on the law then the law probably defines "month" and someone on this site could examine the law to help you find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the legal definition of a month in your jurisdiction.

For example, a month in Australia is universally defined as a calendar month e.g. from 10 Dec 2018 to 9 Jan 2019 inclusive. In this jurisdiction, 4 weeks is not a month (unless the particular month in question is February in a non-leap year).